# In a triangle $ABC$,$AD,BE,CF$ are the altitudes and $R$ is the circumradius,then find the radius of the circle $DEF.$

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

In a triangle $ABC$,$AD,BE,CF$ are the altitudes and $R$ is the circumradius,then find the radius of the circle $DEF.$

---

This triangle is not given to be equilateral or anything else.Only the three altitudes are given which meet at the orthicenter.I do not find any way to find the radius of the circle $DEF.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle through the feet of the altitudes is the [nine-point circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_circle), i.e. the circumcircle of the medial triangle. It follows that its circumradius is just $\frac{R}{2}$.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you tell me or give me the link to the circumradius of median triangle is half of the circumradius of the parent triangle.

Comment: @Brahmagupta: the medial triangle and the original triangle are homothetic. I added a picture to make it clear.